# Security error when executing same snippet more than one time

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Today I noticed an error on one snippet saying

> Error : Error executing AG js: SecurityError: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.

I thought it is an error in that code, may be some dead script links.

Then I saw the same error for some other snippets too.

[image]

So it is an issue with Stack Snippets.

It is not occurring for first run. But it is occurring for all consecutive runs.

#### To repro

1. Run a snippet.
2. Perform anything in the snippet. But not that the window should not reloaded.
3. Click on the Run button again.

A sample snippet (run it 2-3 times)

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

**OS:** Windows 10
**Browser:** Chrome/60.0.3112.113

Comment: You should add your browser and version. For me on Chrome 60.0.3112.113 I can click the "Run code snippet" button in your example forever without any error message showing up. Or did I misunderstand what has to be done to reproduce it?

Comment: @BDL will update now. mine is the same version on windows 10.

Comment: Same here. still can't reproduce.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either. I have refreshed it a ton of times, nothing happens. Could be it only applies to specific snippets

Comment: @LunarWatcher it happens to all snippets. please check this image of the snippet on this post https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmWEw.png

Comment: @BDL I am getting that issue. please check the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmWEw.png

Comment: It might be related to certain browser extensions, do you also get it in an private window using https?

Comment: @Ferrybig yeah. Previously I didn't got this error. It started today.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it in Firefox 55.0.3 on Linux...

Comment: Weird. Printing out the sessionStorage in the Chrome console (```console.log(window.sessionStorage)```) it seems that Stackoverflow indeed uses it to store some page history. Apparently the snippets feature is somehow interfering with that on your machine.

Comment: the snippet is running from another domain stacksnippets.net and if the snippet try to access the sessionstorage, it can't because the main domain is different

Comment: It would seem so, but it doesn't do that on my machine. Whatever script is loaded from stacksnippets.net (which is attached to the page the first time you click the run button) does not access the sessionStorage at all. At least a plain text search tells me it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried disabling extensions? Disabling my adblocker made this go away